# What does "degrees of freedom" mean in the context of cointegration?

Tags: cointegration, degrees-of-freedom

I recently read a paper where the author says they used cointegration "with two degrees of freedom". What does degrees of freedom mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I'm speculating here without more context, but if two or more nonstationary processes are cointegrated, there is some linear combination of the processes that is stationary.  Said another way, the processes revert to some mean state with respect to one another.

These stochastic processes could be multidimensional (e.g. $Y_i$ moves with respect to two dimensions) and has more than one 'degree of freedom,' so to speak.

I concede that this is very confusing because of the meaning that the phrase 'degrees of freedom' have in the stats context.